# Cypress unable to click on custom button

Tags: cypress

I am automating a test on a page and I need to click the "Add images" button. But it's not reacting

```
<button class="btn btn-default awe-hidden" id="html5button" onclick="$('#html5files').click();return false;">Add images</button>
```

I have tried

1. `cy.get('button').contains('Add images').click()`
2. `cy.get('button').contains('Add images').invoke('show').click()`
3. `cy.get('button').contains('Add images').invoke('show').click({force: true})`
4. `cy.get('button').contains('Add images').trigger('mouseover').dblclick()`
5. Also tried trigger `'mousedown'`, short wait then `'mouseup'`
6. Also tried `cy.contains('Add images').click()`

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please provide the error message/stacktrace of your failing test?

Comment: It may be because the onclick contains jquery code. Try using [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) `cy.get('button').realClick()`

Comment: Thanks @DieGraueEminenz but there is no error message displayed.

Comment: @Sarah thank you that solves it :) If you post it as the answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onclick()` event handler contains a jQuery expression, but I suspect Cypress doesn't handle it properly.

You can use [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) instead

```
cy.get('button').realClick()
```